# Does UCWA support for the chat room using REST

Tags: ucwa

Just wondering does UCWA support for function to create a robot and join a chat room?

Since I have searched through the UCWA resource, I find it no where.

Thanks

Comment: For the purpose of clarity, how would you define a chat room and what are you hoping to achieve by having a robot join one?

Comment: I mean the persistent chat room, I would like to pragmatically send messages using a robot to the persistent chat room.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Look here [Communication Tasks for UCWA](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/KeyTasks-CommunicationTasks), [communication resource](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-communication) and [addParticipant resource](https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/Resources-addParticipant)